# Fastest chrome.windows.create approach

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

**Disclaimer**:
This is a code-golf style issue.  I want to understand how to shave milliseconds off a page load.  Please do not downvote merely because this is "irrelevant."  It is entirely appropriate to ask a "how to do x fast" style question on SO, rather than just "how to make x work."  The question has general applicability because it relates to the inner workings of chrome extensions.

My manifest declares a certain hotkey and does the following when that hotkey is pressed:

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command){windowOpen();});
function windowOpen(){
    chrome.windows.create({
        url:"popup/main.html",
        type:'popup',
        focused:true,
    });
}
```

I have three very closely related issues, they ultimately related to the question: **How can I speed up the process of displaying the window at: "popup/main.html"?**

**Question 1.**
Looking at the chrome developer tools timeline, a handful of events happen before the window is created.  In total this results in about a 80ms delay.  Here is one example of an event that is occurring:

[image: Example]

If I click the link on the right, to view the code, I am shown a page for some some javascript, which is clearly somehow built into the chrome extension runtime. Here are the first few lines of that page:

```
 (function(define, require, requireNative, requireAsync, exports, console, privates,$Array, $Function, $JSON, $Object, $RegExp, $String, $Error) {'use strict';// Copyright 2015 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

// This module implements the registration of guestview elements when
// permissions are not available. These elements exist only to provide a useful
// error message when developers attempt to use them.
```

I'm assuming that this script must load, that it is a part of the chrome extension overhead.  However, are there any steps that can be taken to tweak this overhead to increase performance?

**Question 2.**
I notice in my timeline that the first "event" ticks in at about 35 ms.  Is this a product of the dev tool, or is there some reason, perhaps based on the approach I am using, for the delay?

**Question 3.**
Is there any approach that will produce the desired result, of showing the user the html page at popup/main.html in a new window, that is faster than the method I am using (with the hotkey call etc)?

I appreciate any thoughts that you may have!

Comment: It's the internal overhead. No way to reduce it except for altering chromium code. You can submit a feature request on https://crbug.com and complain they rob us of 5 frames at 60 fps (this is huge).

Comment: Chromium developers are working on a [tangentially related problem](https://crbug.com/636655) and intend to speed up creation of the extension execution context [substantially](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1IfBBZ7sRgNOX_hWQZhXJ2nPelmjoaYIjbqFXEbmYvXc/edit#).